# Cannot destroy php session in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

When I signout, I call the following to destroy the session.  It works in other browsers but in Chrome, the session is still there.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Please help if I there's a special way to do it in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: maybe you have another window of chrome which this issue happened, please close all chrome windows.

Comment: i always start session.  this was working previously but i don't know what happened, it suddenly won't destroy session. i was not touching the code for my signout for a very long time but suddenly i cannot destroy session

Comment: sorry, my fault, i think i have changed my code so it was not entering the signout() method... sorry for the trouble, i changed it and it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, check [the manual](http://php.net/session_destroy):

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

session is  stored on server - it have nothing to do with browser ( in  browser could be only cookie  with session id or something like )